# Is it safe to delete from SortedList during iteration

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerator

My question is is it safe for enumerator to remove item from SortedList?

```
SortedList<decimal, string> myDictionary;
// omitted code

IEnumerator<decimal, string> enum = myDictionary.GetEnumerator();

while(enum.MoveNext)
{
  // is it ok to remove here?
  myDictionary.Remove(enum.Current.Key);
}
```

Comment: No. You should get an InvalidOperationExcpetion

Comment: You would also need to rename your variable `enum` to be `@enum` as `enum` is a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly safe, because it won't work :) Please consider querying your collection to acquire items to be deleted (e.g. LINQ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will throw an exception - you cannot modify a collection while iterating over it.

If you think about it a little, you will understand why. If adding or removing from the collection was allowed, you would no longer be iterating over the same collection - you either have too many (adding) or not enough items (removing).

Comment: Bonus points if you can explain why this should not be allowed.

Comment: Here you go: "The index sequence is based on the sort sequence. When an element is added, it is inserted into SortedList in the correct sort order, and the indexing adjusts accordingly. When an element is removed, the indexing also adjusts accordingly. Therefore, the index of a specific key/value pair might change as elements are added or removed from the SortedList object." MSDN, Linked List documentation.

Comment: I was thinking about STL iterators where some of them were safe to delete and some were not.

Comment: Fact that you can smash your fingers with a hammer doesn't mean, that you have to do it :)

Answer (score 4):

As already stated what you are looking to do is not possible. However, an alternative solution would be to simply maintain a list of items marked for deletion and then remove these afterwords. I would also opt for a `foreach` rather than a `while` loop, less code e.g.

```
var removeList = new List<decimal>();
foreach (var item in myDictionary)
{
    // have a condition which indicates which items are to be removed
    if (item.Key > 1)
    {
        removeList.Add(item.Key);
    }
}
```

Or if you are simply trying to retrieve items for deletion, use LINQ

```
var removeList = myDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Key > 1).Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
```

Then just remove them from the list.

```
// remove from the main collection
foreach (var key in removeList)
{
    myDictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your second example will work? I didn't try it out, but your `removeList` is just a query and will also iterate *on the fly* over the list, leading to the same exception as before. I think you need to add a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to get a new one, so that you are able to change your original list.

Comment: @Oliver: +1 good spot, I never tested myself either. Will update

Answer (score 2):

Operations on the list during iterations are not supported in general. The expected behaviour is to throw an exception, but even if a collection fails to do this you must not rely on this working correctly.

You can first copy the elements into another list and then iterate over this new list of items to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

No. An InvalidOperationExcpetion is thrown. I agree that already enumerated items might be deletable since there is a fixed index. However the issue is the following:

The implementation of SortedList is not clever enough to figure out that the removal will have no affect on the further execution of the enumerable. And to keep it simple and performing well, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out it will not work.  However, since the collection is a SortedList you can use the RemoveAt method.

This method has a slightly better memory profile since it requires no overhead as opposed to a O(n) increase using a separate list to keep track of removals.  It would also have a O(n^2) performance profile as opposed to O(n^2 * log(n)).  The RemoveAt method is O(n) since it must perform an array copy.  The Remove method adds a O(log(n)) operation to find the index before internally calling RemoveAt.  All of this is probably of no concern to you, but it is useful know in case you run into situations involving a lot of 'n'.

```
var myDictionary = new SortedList<decimal, string>();

// omitted code

int i = 0;
while (myDictionary.Count > 0 && i < myDictionary.Count)
{
  if (/* predicate to use for removal */)
  {
    myDictionary.RemoveAt(i);
  }
  else
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! If you want to check element `i` in the `if` you can do this using `myDictionary.Values[i]`, as the underlaying list is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution :

```
            int counter= MyDictionary.Count;
            if (counter == 0)
                return;

            for (int i = 0;  i < counter;i++)
            {
                KeyValuePair<MyIdentifier, MyValue> key = (KeyValuePair<MyIdentifier, MyValue>)MyDictionary.ToArray()[i];
                MyIdentifier identifier = null;

                if (key.Key != null)
                    identifier = key.Key as MyIdentifier;

                if (identifier != null)
                    if (MyCondition)
                    {
                        MyDictionary.Remove(identifier);
                        counter--;
                    }
            }
```